# F11 doesn't work but ctrl + F11 works, Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, ctrl

I have a problem in Eclipse with a specific program I'm trying to run. I added an external library xchart which is basically for creating charts in java. Pressing ctrl+F11 runs the program normally but pressing F11 gives me FileNotFoundException even tho I am pretty sure the path is correct. It is I text file I have put inside the package called HistogramText.txt.

```
package mainP;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import org.knowm.xchart.CategoryChart;
import org.knowm.xchart.CategoryChartBuilder;
import org.knowm.xchart.SwingWrapper;
import org.knowm.xchart.demo.charts.ExampleChart;
import org.knowm.xchart.style.Styler.ChartTheme;
import org.knowm.xchart.style.Styler.LegendPosition;

public class HistogramBarChart implements ExampleChart<CategoryChart> {

public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    ExampleChart<CategoryChart> barChart = new HistogramBarChart();
    CategoryChart bchart = barChart.getChart();
    new SwingWrapper<CategoryChart>(bchart).displayChart();

}catch(Exception e) {
System.out.println("");
}
    }

private int[] Temp() throws FileNotFoundException {

    int num = 0;
    int[] arr = new int[12];
    try {
    File file = new File("src/mainP/HistogramText.txt"); 

        Scanner fScan = new Scanner(file);
        while (fScan.hasNext()) {
            num = fScan.nextInt();
            arr[11]++;
            if (num > 100) {
                arr[10]++;
            }

            if (num >= 1 && num <= 10) { // Adding all the values to array positions 0-9
                arr[0]++;
            }

            if (num >= 11 && num <= 20) {
                arr[1]++;
            }

            if (num >= 21 && num <= 30) {
                arr[2]++;
            }

            if (num >= 31 && num <= 40) {
                arr[3]++;
            }

            if (num >= 41 && num <= 50) {
                arr[4]++;
            }

            if (num >= 51 && num <= 60) {
                arr[5]++;
            }

            if (num >= 61 && num <= 70) {
                arr[6]++;
            }

            if (num >= 71 && num <= 80) {
                arr[7]++;
            }

            if (num >= 81 && num <= 90) {
                arr[8]++;
            }

            if (num >= 91 && num <= 100) {
                arr[9]++;
            }
        }

        fScan.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Lmao");
    }

    return arr;
}

public CategoryChart getChart() {
    int[] arr;
        try {
            arr = Temp();


    // Create Chart
    CategoryChart chart = new CategoryChartBuilder().width(800).height(600).title("Histogram Bar Chart")
            .xAxisTitle("Range").yAxisTitle("Numbers").theme(ChartTheme.GGPlot2).build();

    // Customize Chart
    chart.getStyler().setLegendPosition(LegendPosition.InsideNW);
    chart.getStyler().setHasAnnotations(true);
    chart.getStyler().setChartFontColor(Color.black);

    // Series
    chart.addSeries("Numbers in HistrogramText",
            Arrays.asList(new String[] { "1 - 10", "11 - 20", "21 - 30", "31 - 40", "41 - 50", "51 - 60", "61 - 70",
                    "71 - 80", "81 - 90", "91 - 100", "100+", "All numbers" }),
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7], arr[8],
                    arr[9], arr[10], arr[11] }));

    return chart;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

}

}
```

This is pretty much the code. The external Libraries are xchart-3.5.0.jar and xchart-demo-3.5.0.jar

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception FileNotFoundException)) 
FileInputStream.open0(String) line: not available [native method]   
FileInputStream.open(String) line: not available    
FileInputStream.<init>(File) line: not available    
Toolkit$1.run() line: not available 
Toolkit$1.run() line: not available 
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>) line: not available 
[native method] 
Toolkit.initAssistiveTechnologies() line: not available 
Toolkit.<clinit>() line: not available  
Font.<clinit>() line: not available 
AbstractBaseTheme.<clinit>() line: 39   
Styler$ChartTheme.newInstance(Styler$ChartTheme) line: 51   
CategoryChart.<init>(int, int, Styler$ChartTheme) line: 79  
CategoryChart.<init>(CategoryChartBuilder) line: 89 
CategoryChartBuilder.build() line: 53   
HistogramBarChart.getChart() line: 101  
HistogramBarChart.getChart() line: 1    
HistogramBarChart.main(String[]) line: 20
```

And this is the error I get when I run with F11. I'm quite new at programming so some help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl+F11** is "**Run**" and **F11** is "**Debug**". 
Eclipse Oxygen, by default, automatically builds your project when you "Run" it. Since you don't face any errors while running your code, you may ignore the "Debug" error.
 
The error may occur from your debug configuration.
 
Go to Run=>Debug configurations... and remove configurations.
[image]